# Cargar datos de busqueda en inputs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Aun estoy aprendiendo javascript y ahora estoy tratando de cargar los datos del resultado de una búsqueda en sus respectivos inputs. Tengo mi botón que llama a la función Buscar() y lo que quiero es que cargue el nombre, sexo, fecha de nacimiento y el id en sus respectivos inputs, el código de búsqueda de datos si esta probado y muestra los datos requeridos, pero cuando hago click en seleccionar solo me muestra [object HTMLInputElement] y se borran los inputs. Espero me puedan ayudar

```js
function Buscar() {
            var dni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
            var id = document.getElementById("idEntidad");
            var nom = document.getElementById("nombre");
            var fech = document.getElementById("fechaNac");
            var sex = document.getElementById("sexo");
            var tbody = document.getElementById("tbDatos");                             
            $.get("/Topico/listarPaciente/?dniPaciente=" + dni, function (data) {
                if (data == "" || data == NaN) {
                    error("DNI incorrecto o usuario no registrado");
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                        
                        id += data[i].idEntidad;
                        fech += data[i].fechaNac;
                        nom += data[i].nombre;                        
                        sex += data[i].sexo;                        
                    }
                    tbody.innerHTML = nom;
                    tbody.innerHTML = id;
                    tbody.innerHTML = fech;
                    tbody.innerHTML = sex;
                }                
            })
        }
```

```html
<div class="form-inline" id="frmBuscar">  
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dni" style="width:400px" maxlength="8" placeholder="Ingrese DNI" autofocus>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="Buscar()" value="Seleccionar" />
</div>


<div class="form-group row" id="tbDatos">
            <input asp-for="idEntidad" class="form-control" type="hidden" id="idEntidad" />
            <input asp-for="fechaNac" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" min="01-01-1930" style="display:none" />
            <div class="col-6">
                <label asp-for="nombre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" readonly />
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <label asp-for="sexo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="sexo" class="form-control" id="sexo" readonly />
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <label asp-for="edad" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="edad" class="form-control" id="edad" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias probar usando lo siguiente al asignar el valor a los inputs:

```
document.getElementById("idEntidad").value = "Valor";
```

O

```
var id = document.getElementById("idEntidad");
id.value = "Valor";
```

Tu Funcion deberia de verse mas o menos asi:

```
function Buscar() {
            var dni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
            var id = document.getElementById("idEntidad");
            var nom = document.getElementById("nombre");
            var fech = document.getElementById("fechaNac");
            var sex = document.getElementById("sexo");                                        
            $.get("/Topico/listarPaciente/?dniPaciente=" + dni, function (data) {
                if (data == "" || data == NaN) {
                    error("DNI incorrecto o usuario no registrado");
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                        
                        id.value = data[i].idEntidad;
                        fech.value = data[i].fechaNac;
                        nom.value = data[i].nombre;                        
                        sex.value = data[i].sexo;                        
                    }
                }                
            })
        }
```

Sin embargo acabo de darme cuenta de que estas usando un tbody y no se por que, si quisieras llenar una tabla talvez este ejemplo te sirva:

```
<table id="tabla" class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="testBody"></tbody>
</table>
<script>
  const items1 = [
    { fecha: "10/17/2022", nombre: "Bruce Wayne" },
    { fecha: "10/18/2022", nombre: "Clark Kent" },
  ];
  const items2 = [
    { fecha: "10/17/2022", nombre: "Wally West" },
    { fecha: "10/18/2022", nombre: "Sheldon Cooper" },
  ];
  function cargarDatosEnTabla(items) {
    const tabla = document.getElementById("testBody");
    items.forEach( item => {
      let row = tabla.insertRow();
      let fecha= row.insertCell(0);
      fecha.innerHTML = item.fecha;
      let nombre = row.insertCell(1);
      name.innerHTML = item.nombre;
    });
  }
  cargarDatosEnTabla(items1);
  cargarDatosEnTabla(items2);
  cargarDatosEnTabla([]);
</script>
```

Comment: no entiendo bien. Podrias ser un poco mas especifico en que parte pongo esos datos modificados o por cual los reemplazo

Comment: Podrias decirme por que usas un tbody, agregue un ejemplo extra de como llenar un tabla por si te sirve, con respecto a lo primero, estas asignando los valores en el for pero te falta poner el .value para que se asigne correctamente

Comment: Una tabla si puedo llenarla, el problema es cuando lo cargo en los inputs como puse en mi pregunta. El codigo lo trate de adaptar porque lo uso para llenar tablas por eso el tbody.

Comment: Fijate en como muestro tu funcion en la respuesta, a eso me refieron con que cambiar la forma en que asignas el valor al input